# PyInstaller and Georgian Characters

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, pyinstaller

I have a code where I print Georgian letters; When I run my code in VSCode the letters appear perfectly, however, when I turn my python file into an executable using PyInstaller, the Georgian letters appear as question marks. I tried printing just the text, putting a "u" ahead of it, and even using unicode codes. They all appear as question marks in the executable file. I do have Georgian keyboard installed on my PC. I use windows 7.

```
print("აააგგგ")
print(u"აააგგგ")
print('\u10A0\u10A0\u10A0\u10A1\u10A1\u10A1')
stop = input("")
```

the output is:

```
??????
??????
??????
```

while its supposed to be:

```
აააგგგ
აააგგგ
აააგგგ
```

Is there a way to make those letters appear normally in the executable file?

Comment: [PyInstaller runs in Windows 8 and newer.](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/requirements.html) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exe output in [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ added the output, however, as I've read, PyInstaller runs fine with Windows 7 it's just not supported anymore. I don't think my current problem with the Georgian characters is somehow connected to the fact that pyinstaller is not supported for me anymore.